# Why cp indicate "is not a directory" on one server and it's okay on another server

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, cp

When I execute this command on my server :

```
cp *index.html saveIndex/$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M)Index.html
```

The shell indicates :

> cp: target 'saveIndex/20180110-0934Index.html' is not a directory

However, this command function on my computer.

Comment: or *index.html matches more than one file on the server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you have multiple `*index` files, and your command looks like:
`cp index.html 1index.html bla-blaindex.html saveIndex/20180110-0934Index.html` and it could be executed if only last argument is a directory, not file name.

You can or run `cp *index.html saveIndex/`, or add seconds at the `date` for new filename and create the script like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
for ifile in *index.html
do
    cp "${ifile}" saveIndex/$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S)Index.html
    sleep 1
done
```

`sleep 1` will allows you to get unique names, but you can use any another suffix you prefer (`$RANDOM` for example or last time modified/changed date, inode of each file) to avoid `sleep 1` waiting.

Inode example:

```
#!/bin/bash
for ifile in *index.html
do
    cp "${ifile}" saveIndex/$(stat -c %i "${ifile}")-$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S)Index.html
done
```